# Django outputting errorlist as string instead of html

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to customize the default error list in django. I've tried following [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format), but the problem is that the supposed html gets outputted as text istead of html:
[image]

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, as the code is pretty much copy-paste from the docs. Code:

## forms.py

```
class DivErrorList(ErrorList):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.as_divs()

    def as_divs(self):
        if not self: return ''
        return '<div class="test">%s</div>' % ''.join(['<div class="error">%s</div>' % e for e in self])
```

## views.py

```
def addUser(request):    
    add_user_form = AddUserForm()
    messages.warning(request, 'message')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_user_form = AddUserForm(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList)

        if add_user_form.is_valid():
            user = add_user_form.save()
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name = 'group_name')
            user.roles.add(customer_group)
            messages.success(request, 'message')
            return redirect('users')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'message')

    context = {
        'add_user_form': add_user_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'users/backend/user/user_add.html', context)
```

## html

```
<div class="w-full mt-6">
    {% include 'components/typography/form_label.html' with label='Gjenta passord' %}
    {{ add_user_form.password2 }}
    {{ add_user_form.password2.errors }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mark the string as "safe", i.e. this:

```
return '<div class="test">%s</div>' % ''.join(['<div class="error">%s</div>' % e for e in self])
```

should be

```
return mark_safe('<div class="test">%s</div>' % ''.join(['<div class="error">%s</div>' % e for e in self]))
```

where `mark_safe` comes from:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```